# Raise to 1/3 gives complex number

Tags: python, numpy

I cannot understand the following output. I would expect Numpy to return `-10` (or an approximation). Why is it a complex number?

```
print((-1000)**(1/3.))
```

Numpy answer

```
(5+8.660254037844384j)
```

Numpy official tutorial says the answer is `nan`. You can find it in the middle of [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial).

Comment: Why do you think `numpy` is involved in this process? Also, have a look at `(5+8.660254037844384j)**3`!

Comment: For the answer to the mathematical half of this question, see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25528/cubic-root-of-negative-numbers. There is more than one cubic root of `-1000`!

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe. I completely forgot about roots of unity. How can I force python to return -10?

Comment: I'm not sure you can.

Comment: @user1700890: You could write your own `cbrt` function, using something like: `def cbrt(x): return copysign(abs(x)**(1/3.), x)`.  If you import `copysign` from `numpy` instead of `math`, this definition should work for arrays as well as floats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are exponentiating a regular Python scalar rather than a numpy array.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.array(-1000) ** (1. / 3))
# nan
```

The difference is that numpy does not automatically promote the result to a complex type, whereas a Python 3 scalar gets promoted to a complex value (in Python 2.7 you would just get a `ValueError`).

As explained in the link @jonrsharpe gave above, negative numbers have multiple cube roots. To get the root you are looking for, you could do something like this:

```
x = -1000
print(np.copysign(np.abs(x) ** (1. / 3), x))
# -10.0
```

---

### Update 1

Mark Dickinson is absolutely right about the underlying cause of the problem - `1. / 3` is not exactly the same as a third because of rounding error, so `x ** (1. / 3)` is not quite the same thing as the cube root of `x`.

A better solution would be to use [`scipy.special.cbrt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.special.cbrt.html), which computes the 'exact' cube root rather than `x ** (1./3)`:

```
from scipy.special import cbrt

print(cbrt(-1000))
# -10.0
```

### Update 2

It's also worth noting that [versions of numpy >= 0.10.0](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.10.0-notes.rst#npcbrt-to-compute-cube-root-for-real-floats) will have a new `np.cbrt` function based on [the C99 `cbrt` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cbrt).

Comment: Thank you, ali_m! Why would not Numpy return -10?

Comment: *All* real (non-zero) numbers have a pair of complex cube roots in addition to a real cube root, not just the negative ones.

Comment: @user1700890: Note that this isn't computing the cube root: it's computing `-1000` to the power `0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125`, which isn't the same thing at all.  Having the power operation guess that you actually wanted a cube root and defer to `cbrt` in this situation would break continuity and in general be a horrible thing to do.  (Should it also guess for 5th roots?  7th roots? Using what criterion?) IEEE 754 *does* define a `rootn` function, which behaves the way you'd expect for odd `n`, giving finite results for negative finite inputs.

Comment: @ali_m: Nice find with `scipy.special.cbrt`.  It would be nice to see Python's math module grow either a `cbrt` or a `rootn` function for this situation.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes, I was hoping there would be a generic `rootn` function somewhere in the Python standard libraries (or at least in numpy). The [scipy source for `cbrt`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/d1203c280a8661536d64f17e6a90d7ef000302d5/scipy/special/cephes/cbrt.c) ultimately comes from cephes, which unfortunately lacks a `rootn`.