# Cardano's formula not working with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, calculus

--- using python 3 ---

Following the equations [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano's_Formula), I tried to find all real roots of an arbitrary third-order-polynomial. Unfortunatelly, my implementation does not yield the correct result and I cannot find the error. Maybe you are able to spot it within a blink of an eye and tell me.

(As you notice, only the roots of the green curve are wrong.)

With best regards

```
import numpy as np
def find_cubic_roots(a,b,c,d):
    # with ax³ + bx² + cx + d = 0
    a,b,c,d = a+0j, b+0j, c+0j, d+0j
    all_ = (a != np.pi)

    Q = (3*a*c - b**2)/ (9*a**2)
    R = (9*a*b*c - 27*a**2*d - 2*b**3) / (54 * a**3)
    D = Q**3 + R**2
    S = (R + np.sqrt(D))**(1/3)
    T = (R - np.sqrt(D))**(1/3)

    result = np.zeros(tuple(list(a.shape) + [3])) + 0j
    result[all_,0] = - b / (3*a) + (S+T)
    result[all_,1] = - b / (3*a)  - (S+T) / 2 + 0.5j * np.sqrt(3) * (S - T)
    result[all_,2] = - b / (3*a)  - (S+T) / 2 -  0.5j * np.sqrt(3) * (S - T)

    return result
```

The example where you see it does not work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = np.array([2.5])
b = np.array([-5])
c = np.array([0])

x = np.linspace(-2,3,100)
for i, d in enumerate([-8,0,8]):
    d = np.array(d)
    roots = find_cubic_roots(a,b,c,d)
    ax.plot(x, a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d, label = "a = %.3f, b = %.3f, c = %.3f, d = %.3f"%(a,b,c,d), color = colors[i])
    print(roots)
    ax.plot(x, x*0)
    ax.scatter(roots,roots*0,  s = 80)
ax.legend(loc = 0)
ax.set_xlim(-2,3)
plt.show()
```

[image: Easy Example]

Output:

```
[[ 2.50852567+0.j        -0.25426283+1.1004545j -0.25426283-1.1004545j]]
[[ 2.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.-0.j]]
[[ 1.51400399+1.46763129j  1.02750817-1.1867528j  -0.54151216-0.28087849j]]
```

Comment: is it python 3 or python 2? because in python 2 `1/3` = 0.

Comment: python3, I will write it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my stab at the solution. Your code fails for the case where `R + np.sqrt(D)` or `R - np.sqrt(D)` is negative. The reason is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231115/raise-to-1-3-gives-complex-number). Basically if you do `a**(1/3)` where `a` is negative, numpy returns a complex number. However, we infact, want `S` and `T` to be real since cube root of a negative real number is simply a negative real number (let's ignore **De Moivre's** theorem for now and focus on the code and not the math). The way to work around it is to check if `S` is real, cast it to real and pass `S` to the function `from scipy.special import cbrt`. Similarly for `T`.
Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import pdb
import math
from scipy.special import cbrt
def find_cubic_roots(a,b,c,d, bp = False):

    a,b,c,d = a+0j, b+0j, c+0j, d+0j
    all_ = (a != np.pi)

    Q = (3*a*c - b**2)/ (9*a**2)
    R = (9*a*b*c - 27*a**2*d - 2*b**3) / (54 * a**3)
    D = Q**3 + R**2
    S = 0 #NEW CALCULATION FOR S STARTS HERE
    if np.isreal(R + np.sqrt(D)):
        S = cbrt(np.real(R + np.sqrt(D)))
    else:
        S = (R + np.sqrt(D))**(1/3)
    T = 0 #NEW CALCULATION FOR T STARTS HERE
    if np.isreal(R - np.sqrt(D)):
        T = cbrt(np.real(R - np.sqrt(D)))
    else:
        T = (R - np.sqrt(D))**(1/3)

    result = np.zeros(tuple(list(a.shape) + [3])) + 0j
    result[all_,0] = - b / (3*a) + (S+T)
    result[all_,1] = - b / (3*a)  - (S+T) / 2 + 0.5j * np.sqrt(3) * (S - T)
    result[all_,2] = - b / (3*a)  - (S+T) / 2 -  0.5j * np.sqrt(3) * (S - T)
    #if bp:
        #pdb.set_trace()
    return result


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = np.array([2.5])
b = np.array([-5])
c = np.array([0])
x = np.linspace(-2,3,100)
for i, d in enumerate([-8,0,8]):
    d = np.array(d)
    if d == 8:
        roots = find_cubic_roots(a,b,c,d, True)
    else:
        roots = find_cubic_roots(a,b,c,d)

    ax.plot(x, a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d, label = "a = %.3f, b = %.3f, c = %.3f, d = %.3f"%(a,b,c,d))
    print(roots)
    ax.plot(x, x*0)
    ax.scatter(roots,roots*0,  s = 80)
ax.legend(loc = 0)
ax.set_xlim(-2,3)
plt.show()
```

DISCLAIMER: The output root gives some warning, which you can *probably* ignore. The output is correct. However, the plotting shows an extra root for some reasons. This is likely due to your plotting code. The printed roots look fine though.

Comment: @varantir my pleasure.