# Why is (-27)**(1.0/3.0) not -3.0 in Python?

Tags: python

In math, you are allowed to take cubic roots of negative numbers, because a negative number multiplied by two other negative numbers results in a negative number. Raising something to a fractional power 1/n is the same as taking the nth root of it. Therefore, the cubic root of -27, or (-27)**(1.0/3.0) comes out to -3.

But in Python 2, when I type in (-27)**(1.0/3.0), it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
```

Python 3 doesn't produce an exception, but it gives a complex number that doesn't look anything like -3:

```
>>> (-27)**(1.0/3.0)
(1.5000000000000004+2.598076211353316j)
```

Why don't I get the result that makes mathematical sense? And is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Reopening. I don't think either of those dupe targets fit; one has no explanation, and the other is talking about a different problem. This question asks for an explanation.

Comment: The problem is that `1.0/3.0` isn't a fraction but a float.

Comment: For a better explanation of all the issues, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31231115/984421.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

-27 has a real cube root (and two non-real cube roots), but `(-27)**(1.0/3.0)` does not mean "take the real cube root of -27".

First, `1.0/3.0` doesn't evaluate to exactly one third, due to the limits of floating-point representation. It evaluates to exactly

```
0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
```

though by default, Python won't print the exact value.

Second, `**` is not a root-finding operation, whether real roots or principal roots or some other choice. It is the exponentiation operator. General exponentiation of negative numbers to arbitrary real powers is messy, and the usual definitions don't match with real nth roots; for example, the usual definition of (-27)^(1/3) would give you the principal root, a complex number, not -3.

Python 2 decides that it's probably better to raise an error for stuff like this unless you make your intentions explicit, for example by exponentiating the absolute value and then applying the sign:

```
def real_nth_root(x, n):
    # approximate
    # if n is even, x must be non-negative, and we'll pick the non-negative root.
    if n % 2 == 0 and x < 0:
        raise ValueError("No real root.")
    return (abs(x) ** (1.0/n)) * (-1 if x < 0 else 1)
```

or by using complex `exp` and `log` to take the principal root:

```
import cmath
def principal_nth_root(x, n):
    # still approximate
    return cmath.exp(cmath.log(x)/n)
```

or by just casting to `complex` for complex exponentiation (equivalent to the exp-log thing up to rounding error):

```
>>> complex(-27)**(1.0/3.0)
(1.5000000000000004+2.598076211353316j)
```

Python 3 uses complex exponentiation for negative-number-to-noninteger, which gives the principal `n`th root for `y == 1.0/n`:

```
>>> (-27)**(1/3)  # Python 3
(1.5000000000000004+2.598076211353316j)
```

Comment: @EricDuminil: True, it'd probably be best to check whether a real root exists instead of assuming it. I've added a check.

Comment: Nice. This answer is now the best one I could find on SO!

Answer (score 3):

The [type coercion rules documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow) by builtin `pow` apply here, since you're using a float for the exponent.

Just make sure that either the base or the exponent is a complex instance and it works:

```
>>> (-27+0j)**(1.0/3.0)
(1.5000000000000004+2.598076211353316j)
>>> (-27)**(complex(1.0/3.0))
(1.5000000000000004+2.598076211353316j)
```

To find all three roots, consider `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.roots([1, 0, 0, 27])
array([-3.0+0.j        ,  1.5+2.59807621j,  1.5-2.59807621j])
```

The list `[1, 0, 0, 27]` here refers to the coefficients of the equation *1x³ + 0x² + 0x + 27*.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Python, or your version of it, supports this function. I pasted the same equation into my Python interpreter, (IDLE) and it solved it, with no errors. I am using Python 3.2.