# numpy.power for array with negative numbers

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

I have a numpy array `arr = np.array([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`.
Then how can I raise every element to the (say) 3/5'th power?

When I try something like this:

```
>>> np.float_power(arr, 3/5)
>>> arr**(3/5)
```

I always get this output:

```
array([       nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,
   0.        , 1.        , 1.16150873, 1.26782173, 1.34910253,
   1.4157205 ])
```

However, `x**(3/5)` should be computable for negative numbers `x`, as it's only the fifth root of `x` cubed!
I think this is because Python doesn't see 3/5 as the 'perfect fraction' 3/5, but as a real number (very) close to 0.6 (for example 0.59999999999999999).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Properties like "a^(b/c) is the c'th real root of the b'th power of a" don't hold when a is negative, even in non-floating-point arithmetic, even when c is odd.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46225028/why-is-271-0-3-0-not-3-0-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take the sign away and reinsert it later:

```
res = np.float_power(abs(arr), 3./5)*np.sign(arr)

[-2.6265278  -2.29739671 -1.93318204 -1.51571657 -1.  0. 1. 1.51571657  1.93318204  2.29739671  2.6265278 ]
```

The [nth root algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm) returns positive values only. I presume the implementation in numpy is similar.

Comment: Mmmh, I'm realizing you have an issue with even numbers... Will have a look into this later.

Comment: Yes, but that's not a problem in my program, as I will always deal with known exponents.